# Where to put a function that is relevant to a type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do you structure your code when you solve similar problems?
I have an interface that just defines what js objects should look like

```
interface Secured {
    security: string;
}
```

And also I have a function that checks whether the object inplements my interface

```
const isSecured: (x: any) => x is Secured = ......
```

I don't know how people structure their code in these situations but I have an idea

```
class Secured {
    static Type = interface......
    static isSecured = .....
}
```

But this doesn't look good, I think

Comment: If you're using modules, I'd do `export interface Secured { ...` and `export const isSecured = ...` then import either of them wherever they're needed. If you're not using modules... why? 

Comment: Either way, I feel like this question would be more fitting for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) since it's pretty opinion-based

Answer (score 3):

Usually the code is structured using modules.

It looks like `Secured` and `isSecured` are always going to be used together, so it seems natural to
 put them in one module, for example in `secured.ts`.

When you have more than one things exported from a module, you can use named exports for all the things:

```
export interface Secured {
    security: string;
}

export const isSecured: (x: any) => x is Secured = ......
```

Then, when importing from that module, you can use namespace import to have `Secured` and `isSecured` available in the namespace of your choice:

```
import * as Secured from '.../relative-path-to/secured'; 
// here we choose Secured as namespace name


let s: Secured.Secured | SomethingElse;

if (Secured.isSecured(s)) {
}
```

Or you can use named imports and rename some of them:

```
import {Secured as SecuredType, isSecured} from '.../relative-path-to/secured'; 

let s: SecuredType | SomethingElse;

if (isSecured(s)) {
}
```